# Function appends a row to a table as string

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have yet to do this before. But how would I go about adding a row to a table? This is what I currently have:

index.ejs

```
<table id="addressTable" class='table-primary table-bordered table' style='border-spacing: 10px;'>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Street Address:</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>State</td>
            <td>Zip Code</td>
            <td>Residency Length (years)</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Current Address</td>
            <td><input type="string" id="currentStreetAddress" name="currentStreetAddress" placeholder="Current Street Address"/></td>
            <td><input type="string" id="currentCity" name="currentCity" placeholder="Current City"/></td>
            <td><input type="string" id="currentState" name="currentState" placeholder="Current State"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="currentZip" name="currentZip" placeholder="Current Zip Code"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="currentLength" name="currentLength" placeholder="Current Residency Length"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mailing Address</td>
            <td><input type="string" id="mailingStreetAddress" name="mailingStreetAddress" placeholder="Mailing Street Address"/></td>
            <td><input type="string" id="mailingCity" name="mailingCity" placeholder="Mailing City"/></td>
            <td><input type="string" id="mailingState" name="mailingState" placeholder="Mailing State"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="mailingZip" name="mailingZip" placeholder="Mailing Zip Code"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="mailingLength" name="mailingLength" placeholder="Mailing Residency Length"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<button type='button' onclick="addRowAddress()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Row</button><br /><br />
```

addRow.js

```js
function addRowAddress(){
    var empTab = document.getElementById('addressTable');

    var addAddress = '<tr><td>Previous Address</td><td><input type="string" id="previousStreetAddress" name="previousStreetAddress" placeholder="Previous Street Address"/></td><td><input type="string" id="previousCity" name="previousCity" placeholder="Previous City"/></td><td><input type="string" id="previousState" name="previousState" placeholder="Previous State"/></td><td><input type="number" id="previousZip" name="previousZip" placeholder="Previous Zip Code"/></td><td><input type="number" id="previousLength" name="previousLength" placeholder="Previous Residency Length"/></td></tr>'

    empTab.append(addAddress);
}
```

When I click the button to addRow, it outputs all the HTML as a string instead of using the HTML to add to the table. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a row into the tbody, get a reference to it and add it there.

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];


// Insert a row in the table at the last row
var newRow = tableRef.insertRow();

// Insert a cell in the row at index 0
var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);

// Append a text node to the cell
var newText  = document.createTextNode('New row');

newCell.appendChild(newText);
```